# Was bedeutet „knixen“?

Tags: single-word-request, poetry, lyrics

Das Ende Mörikes (danach von Hugo Wolf vertonten) Gedichtes *Die Storchenbotschaft*  lautet :

> Da klappern die Störche im lustigsten Ton,
>   sie nicken und *knixen* und fliegen davon.

Ist *knixen* ein erfundenes Wort? Ich finde seine Bedeutung in keinem Wörterbuch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Das Wort "knicksen", früher auch "[knixen](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GK08861)", bedeutet "einen Knicks machen" (veraltet  auch "[Knix](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GK08859)").

Der Knicks ist das damenhafte Pendant zur Verbeugung. Mehr Informationen zum Knicks als solchen gibt es bei [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knicks_%28H%C3%B6flichkeitsform%29), Wörterbuch-Informationen gibt es unter anderem beim [Duden Online](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/knicksen), ein Bild ist auf [Bild.de](http://bilder.bild.de/fotos-skaliert/knicks-27000822-mbhf-24852452/3,w=308,c=0.bild.jpeg) zu finden.